# Promise chaining (angular javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, chaining

So I have a few functions that all make async calls to a service. I wan't them all to execute after the previous one is complete but only if the previous one didn't fail. It looks something like this:

```
var fn1 = function() {
    var promise = aService.fn1();
    var successCallback = function(response) {
        return true;
    };
    var errorCallback = function() {
        return false;
    };
    return promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback);
};
var fn2 = function() {
    var promise = aService.fn2();
    var successCallback = function(response) {
        return true;
    };
    var errorCallback = function() {
        return false;
    };
    return promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback);
};
var fn3 = function() {
    var promise = aService.fn3();
    var successCallback = function(response) {
        return true;
    };
    var errorCallback = function() {
        return false;
    };
    return promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback);
};

fn1().then(function(resp){
    if (resp)
    {
        fn2().then(function(resp){
            if (resp)
            {
                fn3().then(function(resp){
                    if (resp)
                    {
                        // all functions have been called in order were successful
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The execution at the end looks pretty bad the more function are added to this chain. I wan't to know if there is another way I can structure this in way so it behaves the same but doesn't create a huge tree of chained async calls. If I can keep it on the same indentation that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify the error callbacks to return `$q.reject()` instead of `false`, i.e.:

```
var fn1 = function() {
    var promise = aService.fn1();
    var successCallback = function(response) {
        // no return needed, unless the next stage
        // requires the results of this stage
    };
    var errorCallback = function() {
        return $q.reject();
    };
    return promise.then(successCallback, errorCallback);
};
```

The the chaining becomes:

```
fn1()
    .then(function() {
        return fn2();
    })
    .then(function() {
        return fn3();
    })
    .then(function() {
        // ALL SUCCEEDED HERE
    });
```

---

In fact you do not even have to write that painful code in `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, i.e. the following will also do the job:

```
aService.fn1()
    .then(function() {
        return aService.fn2();
    })
    .then(function() {
        return aService.fn3();
    })
    .then(function() {
        // ALL SUCCEEDED HERE
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. I can't use your third solution though as in my real code I have some logic in the error- and success-callbacks of fn1, fn2 and fn3. However the second solution you provided was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @martingo89 see https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-thensuccess-fail-anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

If your service functions are already promisified, you can keep things extremely short:

```
aService.fn1()
.then(aService.fn2.bind(aService))
.then(aService.fn3.bind(aService))
.then(function(){
    // all functions have been called in order and were successful
});
```